# C++ store reference to class member in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, openframeworks

Consider a Drag object:

```
class Drag {
public:
    Drag(ofVec3f _pos);
    ofVec3f pos;
}
```

Position is stored when a new instance is created:

```
Drag::Drag(ofVec3f _pos) {
    pos = _pos;
}
```

Position is updated when mouse moves:

```
void Drag::mouseMoved() {
    pos.x = ofGetMouseX();
    pos.y = ofGetMouseY();
}
```

---

In the application's main class (testApp in openframeworks):

```
class testApp : public ofBaseApp {
    public:
        vector<Drag> drags;
        vector<ofVec3f *> points;
}
```

Create a Drag when the mouse is pressed and store its position in a vector called points:

```
void testApp::mousePressed(int x, int y, int button) {
    Drag drag = Drag(ofVec3f(ofGetMouseX(), ofGetMouseY(), 0));
    drags.push_back(drag);
    points.push_back(&drag.pos);
}
```

Now when the drag is moved, I can see its position update, but points[0] doesn't change:

```
void testApp::update(){
    if (!drags.size()) return;
    cout << drags[0].pos.x << ", " << drags[0].pos.y << endl;
    cout << &points[0]->x << ", " << &points[0]->y << endl;
}
```

If the type of points is `vector<ofVec3f>` it seems that points[0] is a copy of the initial drags[0].pos. If it is `vector<ofVec3f *>` then it seems to store an address on memory that is equal to &drag.

How can I make points[0] point to drags[0].pos and get its x,y values updated when drags[0].pos.x and drags[0].pos.y are updated?

How can I make points[0] be a **reference** to drags[0].pos?

---

**Edit:** Thanks to yonilevy for pointing me in the right direction. Here's the working  example, updated using std::list:

```
// testApp.h
list<Drag> drags;
vector<ofVec3f *> points;

// testApp::mousePressed
drags.push_back(Drag(ofVec3f(ofGetMouseX(), ofGetMouseY(), 0)));
points.push_back(&drags.back().pos);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in thinking storing `&drag.pos` will help you keep track of `drag`'s position, while in fact you are storing an address that will become meaningless by the end of that scope. Since `drag` is a local variable, living on the stack, it will be gone by the end of the scope in which it was created. Even storing the address of the copy of `drag` that's being created by the vector when you `push_back` won't help in this case, since it will also become invalid once the vector grows in physical size and has to move all of its stuff to a different place in memory.

What you could do, is make sure the actual Drag object you push to the vector remains the only one around, by allocating it on the heap and pushing a (smart) pointer to it into the vector. That way, you can keep a pointer to its internal `pos` in a vector just like you did, and it will be valid as long as the other vector is.

Comment: It will stop working if you push a bunch of other drags, as I've mentioned in the answer- once a vector reaches its full memory capacity it reallocates and copies all of its contained objects over, and that would make your pointer invalid again. Either use a std::list or allocate drag on the heap.

Comment: You're right. It did stop working after more drags[n].pos were pushed into points. I tried with std:list but it had the same result. Haven't tried allocation on heap yet, is it really necessary? In Actionscript or Java it would be straightforward points[n] = drags[n].pos, done. There must be a simple way to do that in C++... Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Ok, I got it working with std::list. In my previous comment I was using `list<ofVec3f *> points` and that didn't work. Actually points can be vector<ofVec3f *>, but drags should be `list<Drag> drags`. I've edited the question to clarify that in the example.

Comment: Well the list approach might work but it's kind of a lame solution IMO. You mentioned Java and Actionscript, you need to understand that in those languages you are always holding/passing pointers to objects, the equivalent in C++ would be to allocate the `drag` objects on the heap and store pointers to them in the container.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot store references inside a vector, but you can store a `std::reference_wrapper<ofVec3f>`.

```
std::vector< std::reference_wrapper<ofVec3f> > v;
ofVec3f vec;
v.push_back(std::ref(vec));
```

Storing a pointer works as well. You just need to dereference it correctly with `operator*` or `operator->`.

```
std::vector< ofVec3f* > pv;
ofVec3f vec;
pv.push_back(&vec);
pv.front()->x;
```

**About address equality** That the addresses are the same as the address of the drag object is normal. The vector is the first member and so they have the same address (this is only guaranteed to be actually the case with POD types).

Comment: I don't think this addresses the real issue here which is storing an irrelevant pointer/reference, see my answer.

Comment: @pmr: std::reference_wrapper (C++11) is not available in openframeworks yet. And the pointer was already being used as you said (except that it was [0]-> instead of front()->) and this was not working.